# Loading Image data uploaded on drive in numpy array on Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, image-segmentation

I am working on a deep learning project (image segmentation) and decided to move my work to google colab. I uploaded the notebook and the data then used the following code to mount the drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/mydrive')
```

The data is in the format of two folders; one containing the images (input data, in .jpg format) and the other contains their masks (ground Truth, in .png format) each 2600 image. I use the following code to load them.

```
filelist_trainx = sorted(glob.glob('drive/My Drive/Data/Trainx/*.jpg'), key=numericalSort)
X_train = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist_trainx])

filelist_trainy = sorted(glob.glob('drive/My Drive/Data/Trainy/*.png'), key=numericalSort)
Y_train = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist_trainy])
```

When loading the X_train, it does not take any time ,but when running the Y_train it takes so long and I end interrupting the execution of the cell. Anyone knows why does this happen? considering that both of the files contains data of the same dimension and low storage -18 MB total-. here is a sample of the images.
[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIpm3.png)

Comment: Are you accessing your data from your drive? That will cause issues and does take time.

Comment: A fix around is to copy your data to colab itself and not access it directly from your google drive.